# Modelling Entities with lose association

Tags: java, jpa

Sorry for the lack of code examples, but I am still at the drawing board level for modelling an existing table in our application in JPA. This table contains basically business log information. Something like the following:

```
| id     |    timestamp |   key |  sessionid
|     1  |     10:22:21 |     1 |       1234
|     2  |     10:22:23 |     2 |       1234
|     3  |     10:22:31 |     1 |       2345
|     4  |     10:22:33 |     2 |       2345
|     5  |     10:22:35 |     3 |       2345
```

What I need to do is iterate over all the rows grouped by sessionid or something similar. Think of it in terms of selecting and grouping information of sessions. I know group by doesn't work without aggregation functions but what I am looking for is what you would imagine it would deliver if you could group by sessionid. I.e. rows of collections of entries with the same sessionid. 
The only way I can think of achieving this is loading all rows into memory and grouping them myself.

Just to qualify the question. It would be acceptable to select all with key 1 and navigate over a one-to-many of the others with the same sessionid but I don't know of anyway to limit a one-to-many on one column based on values in another column. Discriminator based table inheritance is not an options as key just increments.

Comment: Hi, if i understood what you want, you basically want an entity that would contain an Map<String,List<LogInfo>> where the String key would be your sessionId and List<LogInfo> would contain you table rows ?

Comment: Yes or just a List<List<LogInfo>>

Comment: I mean it seems to me a perfectly natural way of saving such data and I can easily process it in SQL. For example join the rows with key 1 to the rows with key 2. I just cant find any easy way of processing it in hibernate in any way.